# Zend 2.0 with Smarty: display Zend Form on .tpl file

Tags: php, zend-framework2, smarty, zend-form

I have trouble in the Zend 2.0.
I made a tutorial: https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html
and then I implemented the Smarty by: [How can Smarty 3 be Used with Zend Framework 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344951/how-can-smarty-3-be-used-with-zend-framework-2)
Displaying the Form Zend_From in .phtml looks like this:

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', array('action' => 'add')));
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

But how to display `$this->form` i Smarty template?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
{assign var="form" value=$this->form}
{assign var="attr" value=$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('album', ['action' => 'add']))}
{assign var="prep" value=$form->prepare()}
{$this->form()->openTag($this->form)}
{$this->formCollection($this->form)}
{$this->form()->closeTag()}
```